# Problem installing MXNet.jl using Julia1.2 in UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: julia, mxnet, julia-gpu, mxnet.jl

I am having some trouble installing "MXNet.jl" package in julia.

1) I first tryed typing:

```
 (v1.2) pkg> add MXNet
```

and I get this:

```
(v1.2) pkg> add MXNet
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.2/Project.toml`
 [no changes]
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.2/Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]
```

At this point, nothing wrong was going on. There were no error messages thrown. Nice. Now, I went back to the Julia REPL and tried to use the module, for which I wrote:

```
julia> using MXNet
[ Info: Precompiling MXNet [a7949054-b901-59c6-b8e3-7238c29bf7f0]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: IOError: open: permission denied (EACCES)
Stacktrace:
 [1] uv_error at ./libuv.jl:90 [inlined]
 [2] open(::String, ::UInt16, ::UInt16) at ./filesystem.jl:81
 [3] touch(::String) at ./file.jl:404
 [4] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/base.jl:60
 [5] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [7] include at ./Base.jl:31 [inlined]
 [8] include(::String) at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/MXNet.jl:25
 [9] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/MXNet.jl:138
 [10] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [11] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [12] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [13] top-level scope at none:2
 [14] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [15] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:432
 [16] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/base.jl:57
in expression starting at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/MXNet.jl:138
ERROR: Failed to precompile MXNet [a7949054-b901-59c6-b8e3-7238c29bf7f0] to /home/gbrunini/.julia/compiled/v1.2/MXNet/Sc0jU.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1253
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1013
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:911
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:906
```

and all this error messages where thrown. Knowing my limitations with regards to all this errors I went to my second attempt, which consisted in what follows...

2) My second approach consisted in using brute force, so I copied and paste all the github scr folder for the julia MXNet.jl package to a given folder in my personal Desktop. This was done subroutine by subroutine, folder by folder, until I copied every file and folder. So it is fair to say that the scr folder in this link:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/julia/src
looks excatly like mine now.

Now, I went to my folder and proceeded as if "MXNet.jl" were any other ordinary function I used in the past, so I type (On julia REPL):

```
julia> include("MXNet.jl")
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Cannot find or load libmxnet.so. Please see the document on how to build it.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/Desktop/TRABAJOS/MTI/MTI_Neural_network/MTI_ejemplo_simple_3/base.jl:55
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [5] include at ./Base.jl:31 [inlined]
 [6] include(::String) at /home/gbrunini/Desktop/TRABAJOS/MTI/MTI_Neural_network/MTI_ejemplo_simple_3/MXNet.jl:25
 [7] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/Desktop/TRABAJOS/MTI/MTI_Neural_network/MTI_ejemplo_simple_3/MXNet.jl:150
 [8] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [10] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [11] include(::String) at ./client.jl:431
 [12] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
in expression starting at /home/gbrunini/Desktop/TRABAJOS/MTI/MTI_Neural_network/MTI_ejemplo_simple_3/base.jl:51
in expression starting at /home/gbrunini/Desktop/TRABAJOS/MTI/MTI_Neural_network/MTI_ejemplo_simple_3/MXNet.jl:150
```

Which returned all this error message.

My assumption is that there is something wrong with this **libmxnet.so** (I don't know what that is...) and I am tempted to follow **steps 1-3** on this documentation[(MXNet istallation guide)](https://mxnet.apache.org/get_started/ubuntu_setup), but I dont want to screw things up as I really dont know what any of the following commands do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git ninja-build ccache libopenblas-dev libopencv-dev cmake 
git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet.git mxnet
cd mxnet
cp config/linux.cmake config.cmake  # or config/linux_gpu.cmake for build with CUDA
rm -rf build
mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake -GNinja ..
cmake --build .
```

nor what any of the followings do for the Julia:

```
mkdir julia-depot
export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=$HOME/julia/julia-depot
```

a) whats a depot?
b) whats a environment variable (I looked online, and It confusses me...)

```
export MXNET_HOME=$HOME/incubator-mxnet
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/incubator-mxnet/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so:$LD_PRELOAD
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/julia/julia-1.0.3/bin:$PATH
export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=$HOME/julia/julia-depot
export MXNET_HOME=$HOME/incubator-mxnet
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/incubator-mxnet/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so:$LD_PRELOAD
julia --color=yes --project=./ -e \
      'using Pkg; \
       Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(name="MXNet", path = joinpath(ENV["MXNET_HOME"], "julia")))'
```

I really just want to install MXNet.jl and use it. If I understand all the rest as a side-efftect the better, but I settle with having all correctly installed, so for short:

1. What is the problem I am having?,
2. Do I fix it by just "copying and pasteing" the instructions in the documentation steps?
3. If not, how do I install MXNet.jl?,
4. Am I conffusing GPU with CPU(my option) installation? what changes
   between the both?. I don't think that has anything to do with what happens here, but....

Thanks a lot in advance I hope you are all doing Ok.

- UBUNTU 16.4

```
julia> versioninfo()
    Julia Version 1.2.0
    Commit c6da87ff4b (2019-08-20 00:03 UTC)
    Platform Info:
      OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
      CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2310 CPU @ 2.90GHz
      WORD_SIZE: 64
      LIBM: libopenlibm
      LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, sandybridge)
```

EDIT:

Following @Przemyslaw I went and installed the lastest julia version, julia1.4. I was hopping that by doing this, the permissions for writing into `.julia` would be fixed. However, the problem remains. I still get the following messages:

```
(@v1.4) pkg> add MXNet
   Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
   Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
  Resolving package versions...
   Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.4/Project.toml`
  [a7949054] + MXNet v1.5.0
   Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.4/Manifest.toml`
  [9e28174c] + BinDeps v1.0.1
  [682c06a0] + JSON v0.21.0
  [a7949054] + MXNet v1.5.0
  [69de0a69] + Parsers v1.0.2
  [30578b45] + URIParser v0.4.1
  [8ba89e20] + Distributed 
  [a63ad114] + Mmap 
  [8dfed614] + Test 

julia> using MXNet
[ Info: Precompiling MXNet [a7949054-b901-59c6-b8e3-7238c29bf7f0]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: IOError: open: permission denied (EACCES)
Stacktrace:
 [1] uv_error at ./libuv.jl:97 [inlined]
 [2] open(::String, ::UInt16, ::UInt16) at ./filesystem.jl:87
 [3] touch(::String) at ./file.jl:422
 [4] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/base.jl:60
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [6] include(::String) at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/MXNet.jl:25
 [7] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/MXNet.jl:138
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [9] top-level scope at none:2
 [10] eval at ./boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [11] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:449
 [12] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/base.jl:57
in expression starting at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/MXNet/XoVCW/src/MXNet.jl:138
ERROR: Failed to precompile MXNet [a7949054-b901-59c6-b8e3-7238c29bf7f0] to /home/gbrunini/.julia/compiled/v1.4/MXNet/Sc0jU_ATtl5.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1272
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1029
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:927
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:922

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.4.1
Commit 381693d3df* (2020-04-14 17:20 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2310 CPU @ 2.90GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-8.0.1 (ORCJIT, sandybridge)
```

So,

1. Why is installing a new julia not fixing the issue over `.julia`?
2. All other pakages I have install works fine, is `MXNet.jl` the only package that needs to write over `.julia`?
3. Problem seems related to the lines:

```
    if isempty(MXNET_LIB)
      # touch this file, so that after the user properly build libmxnet, the precompiled
      # MXNet.ji will be re-compiled to get MXNET_LIB properly.
      touch(@__FILE__)
      error("Cannot find or load libmxnet.$(Libdl.dlext). " *
            "Please see the document on how to build it.")
    else
      include_dependency(MXNET_LIB)
    end
```

in the `base.jl` subroutine of MXNet.jl. Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 2):

The output of your `add MXNet` command shows that it is already installed.

However, it fails to precompile because your Julia process does not have sufficient permissions.

Your Julia needs to be able to write to `/home/gbrunini/.julia/`, otherwise the modules will not able to precompile and load. Try to set up permissions and rebuild the package with `build MXNet`

The above folder is your default `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`. You can configure that variable to point store all Julia packages in a different location but this does not seem to be your problem (unless you are unable to configure permission for `/home/gbrunini/.julia/` due some other reason).

The brute-force aproach is never a good way to go since Julia packages have many external dependencies. At Julia 1.2 they were managed by downloading the files when running package `build` (that is why you should rebuild). In the current Julia there is a more elegant solution with Julia artifacts.

Comment: Hi @Przemyslaw First of all, thanks for the quick response. I have edited the question above so we can follow this issue. Basically, I have installed the latest julia version and problem remains... can you have any insigths?(above is some explanation of what I have done)...

Comment: Have you deleted the `/home/gbrunini/.julia/` folder after installing the new version of Julia? or are you using still the old one with all the packages?